# java.util.Scanner issue: stops reading after certain number of characters?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

I'm using Scanner to read in approx 700 lines of text (one word per line), and storing each line/word as an element of String ArrayList constructed with a predetermined 800-element size. However, while debugging in Eclipse's variable mode I noticed that the later elements of the ArrayList weren't initialized at all - it seems Scanner stopped in the middle of a word, on a random line.

- It isn't a problem with the delimiter (I've initialized Scanner both with and without a "\n" delimiter, no difference) or the text content itself -- when I switch around the order of the words, Scanner stops reading at EXACTLY the same number of characters.
- The text file itself isn't very big -- only 6KB.
- I've tried switching from next() to nextLine(), no issue there either

I'm using try with resources:

```
try (Scanner stopwordImport = new Scanner(new File(stopwordFile))) {
        while (stopwordImport.hasNext()) {
            stopWords.add(stopwordImport.nextLine());
        }
```

...so Scanner should be closing.

I'm at a loss...what's going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any exceptions? Any empty catch blocks?

Comment: Any special characters? Try bufferedreader, I've had mirror issues like yours. Or try switching hasNext() to hastNextLine() to see if that affects your stated switch from next() to nextLine()

Comment: Did you try printing the `ArrayList`? There might be an issue/misconfig with the IDE.

Comment: Exceptions: originally caught FileNotFoundExceptions and printed stack trace, changed to general type Exception but no difference...

Comment: What does this even mean `I've initialized Scanner both with and without a "\n" delimiter`?. Also, do like @John said and use `hasNextLine()`. It's better practice.

Comment: Are trying to store each word or each line? Be more clear.

Comment: I have one word on each line, so same thing essentially. "\n" as in I've initialized my Scanner specifying that the delimiter was a new line e.g. Scanner s = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n"). Just changed to hasNextLine(), but still same result..

Comment: If I try to print the later elements of my ArrayList beyond what I see in the debugger, they haven't even been initialized yet (IndexOutOfBounds)

Answer (score 1):

try `FileReader` instead of `File`, so you don't have buffer problems. I had the same problem and this worked for me.